# two pnp switch, can't declare voltage inbetween

Tags: transistors

I am trying to learn electronics and I am analyzing this circuit.
I was wondering why the voltage inbetween Q5 and Q6 is always about 700mV when Q5 is open. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Hint: what's the behavior of the base-emitter junction of Q6?

Comment: When Q5 is Turn-ON (conducts current) all the current that is flowing through R25 resistor is flowing into Q5 collector. Leaving no current for Q6 base current. But when you cut-off Q5. This R25 current can now flow into Q6 base-emitter junction and turn-on the Q6. And the base-emitter junction voltage drop when ON is around 0.7V.  And you have two NPN BJT's in your circuit.

Comment: https://www.rohm.com/datasheet/BC847B/bc847bt116-e

Answer (score 0):

once the voltage goes above about 0.6 to 0.7V  the base begins to accept current readily.

the resistor to the supply limits the amount of current available, so the voltage only reaches 0.65V

the resistor is a good thing too much current into the base can damage the transistor.